# Hiding Paired Bluetooth Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am creating an Android application that interacts with Bluetooth modules. 
**Is there a way to hide the paired device to prevent it from showing in the paired devices list?** The reason for doing this is if I have 20 devices which will only ever interact with my application, there is not much point in them showing up in paired devices list.

Comment: I was thinking might it be possible to connect without pairing?

Comment: No, its not possible to connect without pairing. The process begins with bonding (pairing) a device. Only then can you create the connection through the socket. As far as not showing all devices in the system settings, I don't know but would say probably not. You could create a list of paired devices in your app and only show certain bonded devices